# Should we create separate dataframe for each table in a join query in SparkSQL

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

We need to convert and execute execute hive queries in Spark SQL.The query involves a join between 2 tables.We will create a dataframe and then sparksql queries on top of it.Please find samples hive query along with converted query.

**------Hive query**

```
select a.col1,a.col2,a.col3,b.col4,b.col5,b.col6.b.col7
from table1 a left outer join table2 b
on a.col3=b.col3
```

**-----Spark SQL**

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext
val hiveContext = new org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext(sc)
val q1=hivecontext.sql("select col1,col2,col3,col4 from table1");
val q2=hivecontext.sql("select col3,col5,col6,col7 from table2");
val q3=q1.join(q2,q1("col3")===q2("col3"));
```

But it is also possible for us to execute the entire query in a single data frame as below

**

```
val q5=hivecontext.sql("select 
a.col1,a.col2,a.col3,b.col4,b.col5,b.col6.b.col7
from table1 a left outer join table2 b
on a.col3=b.col3")**
```

I would like to know which of the 2 approach(single vs multiple dataframe) we is better to use in such situation and the advantages over the other in various parameters like performance and readability.

Answer (score 0):

Second approach seems to be wise in all aspects

1. When you run SQL on top of Hive data, HiveContext will run the query in hive and returns the result metadata to Spark. So spark just need to store the resultant metadata set.But in the above case it has to store all the data in hive into its RDD's.
2. Maintaining a single RDD helps in optimizing DAG as well.
3. If you run as a single query even Spark catalyst will optimize it more.
4. It looks even better for Readability.

Comment: _"HiveContext will run the query in Hive"_ > wrong, or at least, ambiguous. In general `HiveContext` gets table(s) information from Hive Metastore, gets list(s) of data files from HDFS, then runs the query in Spark using its native SerDe libs, and finally produces a `DataFrame`. In some specific cases Spark has to use Hive SerDe libs, but still it's not Hive that runs the query.

Comment: When run a hive  query through HiveContext, first catalyst will optimize the query and fires it on the Hive metastore and it returns the result metadata set back to sparkSQL. I hope this is the story that happens when run a hive query using HiveContext.

Comment: The Metastore does not run queries.It just stores metadata. Queries are run against **data files**; that's the job of HiveServer2 + `hive` legacy fat client + `pig`fat client + Spark + whatever.

Comment: I agree with you @SamsonScharfrichter. I mean to say Hive metastore returns the metadata set to sparkSQL and sparkSQL will run the query on the data files on its engine instead of Hive engine. But before getting the metadata from metastore there is Hive compiler which will do some sort of optimizations for you.

Answer (score 0):

Both the approaches are identical. It doesn't matter really from the performance standpoint. Catalyst optimizer will create the same physical plan for both the queries.

Now however there are other aspects to consider. Writing SQL query is generally easy however you loose the compile time type check. If you have a typo or incorrect column name in the SQL it is impossible to find unless you run that on the cluster. However, if you are using dataframe operation the code won't compile. So it helps faster coding speed.

But again writing complex SQL with dataframe APIs is not trivial tasks. So generally I use Dataframe APIs where the operations are relatively easy and use SQL for complex queries.